# Applying multiple IF functions to every row

Tags: vba, excel

I need to apply the following IF functions to every row in columns J, L, and S so that the correct date value is printed in the corresponding cell in row T. For example, cell T2 will have a date printed in it based on the outcome of running these IF functions on J2, L2, and S2; cell T3 will have a date printed in it based on the outcome of running these IF functions on J3, L3, and S3; and so on. Here's what I have got:

```
Sub Test1()
Set firstDate = Range("S2")
If Range("J2") = "GS/CA/SL/GW" Then
    If Range("L2") = "1" Or "2" Or "3" Then
        Range("T2") = DateAdd("ww", 52, firstDate)
    End If

    If Range("L2") = "4" Or "5" Or "6" Then
        Range("T2") = DateAdd("ww", 104, firstDate)
    End If

    If Range("L2") = "7" Or "8" Or "9" Then
        Range("T2") = DateAdd("ww", 156, firstDate)
    End If


End If
End Sub
```

It works on one set of cells at a time if I just redefine all the ranges, but I thought there must be an easier way than pasting and editing the code ~3500 times for all the rows I have to run it on. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow your question correctly I believe you just need a simple loop to adapt your current code.

Try this:

```
Sub loopDate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Dim firstDate As Range
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Range("J" & i) = "GS/CA/SL/GW" Then
            Set firstDate = Range("S" & i)
            Select Case Range("L" & i)
                Case 1 To 3
                    Range("T" & i) = DateAdd("ww", 52, firstDate)
                Case 4 To 6
                    Range("T" & i) = DateAdd("ww", 104, firstDate)
                Case 7 To 9
                    Range("T" & i) = DateAdd("ww", 156, firstDate)
            End Select
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that I started the loop at row 2 since that's what your example used and go until the last used row in column A.  I also changed your `if` logic to a `select case` statement for improved readability.

You may want to just use an equation in cell `T?` instead of using VBA but since I don't know the details I'll assume you have a good reason.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that for some reason, with the changes I made, (deleting `Dim i As Long` and changing `Range("S" & i)` to `Range("S2" & i)` ) every date that ends up in column T ends up being in September, regardless of the date in the neighboring cell in column S. If I just run the code as you wrote it, I get a Compile error: Duplicate declaration in current scope. If I just delete `Dim i As Long` I get a Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error. I am puzzled.

Comment: See my latest edit, I should have had the `firstDate` line inside of the loop.  Does that solve your other problem?  Also, `Select Case` will work with same with strings as well: `Case "Apple"`

Comment: Yes, that appears to have fixed it! This is fantastic. Exactly what I needed. Thank you!